# Return an object using its name in python

Tags: python, object

So, I've create global objects that can be accessed by any method. Now I have to return the objects by a method like this.

```
def get_my_obj  (obj_name):  
    if   obj_name == "abc":  return  abc
    elif obj_name == "xyz":  return  xyz
    elif obj_name == "def":  return  def
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? I have hundreds of these objects.

Comment: is obj_name necessarily a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables-in-python)

Comment: could you share a little more of why would you do this? I'm sure you know the global objects are generally not a good idea.

Comment: Use a `dict` with the objects as values. But first tell us, why you are doing this? What is the problem you are really trying to solve?

Comment: Agreed with the rest of the comments. There's no simple way to do this because this is a Thing That Should Not Be Done. If you have to do it, either kludge it like you're doing or find a better way to implement that functionality.

Comment: `globals()[obj_name]` is the literal answer. Don't do this is the rest of the answer.

Comment: This reeks of being an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve (what is your script/app supposed to be doing)?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do this. Mostly improving on already built code. I looked up dict() and that seems to be the best way to do this.

Comment: There are hundreds of already written objects, they are to be accessed by many methods. I don't even know how many are using it. I know there is a simpler way than me writing 586 return statements. I don't really like the method I was using. But I'm pretty sure that I got my answer above!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through the use of `globals()` in the appropriate file, it is entirely possible for achieve such an evil act.

```
# file1.py

abc = 'foo'
xyz = 'bar'
dfe = 'baz'


def get_my_obj(obj_name):
    return globals()[obj_name]


# file2.py

from file1 import get_my_obj

print(get_my_obj('abc'))  # 'foo'
```

[`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) retrieves variables within the current module. In this case, it may be the  file where it is executed.

Can you do it? Yes. Would I do it? No. Is it my business to decide if you should do it anyway? No.

Comment: I guess this would by my approach, or I may use dict() to get it done. As vile as my approach may be, I think I'd prefer it over correcting the many methods that already use these globals. Thanks again Brian!